# Best approach for 2D Grid Image Segmentation

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-segmentation

I'm working on a project where I need to extract text from grocery discount flyers like the Costco announcement below (retrieved in a random google search, Costco is not the deal here):

[image: example sample image]

If I just run OCR (like with Tesseract in python):

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread('costco.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

I get:

> Cadbury Chocolate
>
> variety pack packet
>
> ere $12.99 i rom hagst 31026 2012
> > 
> > Je laa
> > + a
> > 
> > Wrigley’s Excel Gum variety
> > 
> > Backol 24
> > 
> > $13.79 fom agus 26.202
>
> OFF
>
> Solon Extra virgin olive oil [...]

Which is a lot noisy.

My guess is that splitting the image to its base squares enchances the recognition.

However, I'm confused on how to do it. I can classify images using a CNN, but am not sure about object recognition.

Should I have a sliding window and train several "grid box" objects on a generic CNN and then provide this window data to be classified? How to adapt to distinct object window sizes?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really cool problem. You already have a working model here are a few different ways of going forward with the project.

- Grouping text based on locality. "no segmentation"  [Text region extraction in a document image based on the Delaunay tessellation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0031320302000821)
- Segmentation  [Multiscale Edge-Based Text Extraction from Complex Images](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4036951)
- Training a map of the image then extracting text form the map.  [Multi Oriented Text Detection](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2016/html/Zhang_Multi-Oriented_Text_Detection_CVPR_2016_paper.html)

Training the model to detect boxes followed by extracting the text from each box seems like a very smart direction to move in. This paper talks about the former.  [automatic image segmentation and edge detection](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/995125)  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the directions! I'll look at them and return the check answer as soon as I've figured it out.